# Magento admin and customer email notification not sending

Tags: orders, error, cron, order-email

i am getting this error in cron job.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.' in /home/magento FOLDER/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(47): Mage::throwException('Too late for th...')
#1 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/melmatcb/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#4 /home/melmatcb/public_html/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#5 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the jobs that are executed before this one take longer than whatever you have configured in the admin under System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks).. -> Schedule Ahead for multiplied by 60. Try to increase the value of that setting, or check which cron job(s) take a long time to run.